# Java POI 3.17 Exception org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException. The part /docProps/core.xml failed to be saved in the stream

Tags: java, apache-poi, saxon, xalan

A colleague was struggling with the following error when attempting to write to a new xlsx file using Java POI 3.17 APIs

```
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while saving the package : The part /docProps/core.xml failed to be saved in the stream with marshaller org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.ZipPackagePropertiesMarshaller@4ae061e
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:595)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1539)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:227)
```

The code was able to pass unit tests but failed as part of system tests.
I thought I would share my results here

Comment: can you fix the apparent typo? xlsx is what you probably mean not xslt? also, the answer would be more useful if you provide the code that demonstrated the issue

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have edited my typo. The error occurs when invoking the write(FileOutputStream) method on the Workbook object. I haven't included the code as it was embedded in a wider solution, and I did not require changes to the code as it was an issues with versions of jars on the classpath. I will endeavour to include code example in future, but will need to check with company I work for as it is propriety software.

Comment: In my case it was due to an HTTP timeout of my request, which closes the output stream. It took me a little to find out because my HTTP request went through a **proxy,** which was the one that timed out.

A possible solution is to avoid sending synchronous requests for big file exports, but instead use a websocket which tells the frontend when the export is done and ready to be requested for download.

Answer (score 1):

### Investigation

After digging into the POI code I noticed that POI does not re throw the exception in class [StreamHelper](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/StreamHelper.html) when it attempts to write the org.w3c.dom.Document object to the OutputStream using [transform(Source,Result)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#transform(javax.xml.transform.Source,%20javax.xml.transform.Result))
A TransformerException is being thrown by the Transformer implementation.

```
When a DOMSource is used, saxon9-dom.jar must be on the classpath
```

This is resulting in a *False* being returned from the the saveXmlInStream method resulting in the OpenXML4JRuntimeException being thrown.
I also noted that the unit test was using the JRE 7 Xalan implementation of the Transformer while the system test required Saxon 9.
When we introduced the saxon9.jar to the Test case we were able to replicate the error.

### Solution

We were able to identify the route cause as the 9.1.0.8 implementation of Saxon did not include an implementation for DOMSource. an additional jar saxon9-dom-9.1.0.8.jar was required.

---

Alternatively use saxon9He.jar (9.3 or Higher) which does have an implement for DOMSource